# How to Fetch Access token from my custom controller in asp.net web api 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have implemented the code for generating access token.I am able to get the token from default Token End Point Path(https://localhost:44312/token) when trying to get it from Postman.
However I want to implement Login Controller which internally should call the default token end point and send the response.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Login(UserModel userModel)
        {
  HttpResponseMessage response;
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44312/");               
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("cache-control", "no-cache");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                userModel.grant_type = "password";
                var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "username", userModel.UserName }, { "password", userModel.Password }, { "grant_type", "password" } };
                var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
                response =  client.PostAsync("/token", encodedContent).Result;
             }
                return Ok(response);
  }
```

I get an httpstatus OK response but not the access token. Any guidance in solving the issue would be helpful.

Comment: I am passing back the whole response object.But there is no access token in it.

Comment: What is the content type of the request in the postman? Is it x-www-form-urlencoded?